# Sitefinity News item Publish/Unpublish on Specific Date is not Working

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

When I publish/unpublish News module item on specfic datetime, on CMS backend it show that item was published / Unpublished on that specific datetime.

At frontend webtsite it shows reflection of Publish / Unpublish news item sometimes and sometimes it does not show reflection of Pubish / Unpublish.

On Frontend website, if i add querystring in the URL, then the changes will reflect at frontend page. it seems that there is some cache issue in CMS.

Configuration of web servers:

My Sitfinity CMS website is deployed on three servers in which two are on load balancer and serve only frontend website, 3rd server in only serve CMS backend and only accessible within organization domain and not part of the loadbalancer.

We are using Sitefinity Version 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the CMS server is where the content editing / scheduling is done.

Because CMS and Web servers are all pointing to the same database, they need to be setup as Load Balancing nodes.

Check the 2 articles under this one and configure them properly: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/administration-configure-sitefinity-for-load-balancing

Comment: Do you have the SiteSync module licensed? If so - that would be the right way to do this

Comment: Based on the way you have it setup currently you will want to make your site that content is being entered on has to be able to alert the other site(s) fronend that there was a change and should invalidate cache.  When the site that content is being entered on is not part of the NLB setup it doesn't know to alert and the other frontend servers remain cached.